# Add custom caption to LOT file

Tags: tables, macros, table-of-contents

In my publishing company we have our own template with custom `\tcaption` command which make caption above the table with company's standards (and I don't use table environment). However this command doesn't write information in LOT file, so I can't produce the list of tables. What should I change in CLS file to fix this problem?

I can't simply write `\addcontentsline{lot}` because I have 170 tables.

Comment: Can you *renewcommand* the `\tcaption` command or is it forbidden? If yes can you provide the description of `\tcaption` (arguments etc.)?

Comment: If you can show us some code, preferably in a complete  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), some folks may be able to help....

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is in the class, some good old things should work. Try putting this into the preamble, you don't even have to modify the `.cls` file:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@tcaption\tcaption
\def\my@tcaption[#1]#2{\addcontentsline{lot}{#1}\old@tcaption{#2}}
\def\tcaption{\@dblarg\my@tcaption}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately i have an error ! Use of \my@tcaption doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a {
                             \def \@currenvir {equation}\edef \@currenvline ...
l.716 \end{equation}}

Comment: Well, you likely have an equation in the caption. In that case you have to use the optional argument to `\tcaption` that omits the equation. Equations, new paragraphs etc. cannot propagate to the List of Tables, hence the error.